# NTP is running, system clock still not in time - what gives?

Tags: linux, debian, ntp, time-synchronization

A Debian Stable (5.0.3) server is running `ntpd`, and connected to the internet. Still, the system clock is about 5 minutes wrong.

```
$ /etc/init.d/ntp status
NTP server is running..
```

Relevant parts (I think) of `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 0.europe.pool.ntp.org
server 1.europe.pool.ntp.org
server 2.europe.pool.ntp.org
server 3.europe.pool.ntp.org
```

I know NTP doesn't necessarily bring the clock in time immediately. Still, how many hours or days you need to wait in order to reasonably expect that NTP has done its job and synced the clock?

Am I missing some other configuration file or option, or just doing something wrong? Is [ntp](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/ntp) (instead of e.g. [ntpdate](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/ntpdate)) the right tool for this?  Is there any quick way to check if configuration is correct and whether the chosen NTP servers return the correct time?

**Edit**: output of `ntpq -p` is:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ns1.nexellent.n .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 dnscache-madrid .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 sinister.wzw.tu .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 dnscache-frankf .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

**Edit 2**: Turns out `ntpdate -u 0.europe.pool.ntp.org` command ([suggested by brent](https://serverfault.com/questions/95342/ntp-is-running-system-clock-still-not-in-time-what-gives/95351#95351)) returns

```
17 Dec 17:37:29 ntpdate[14195]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

...even though on other machines that command works fine. So we'll be looking at network/firewall settings for this particular server (which is in a different network, accessed over VPN).

**Resolution**: The culprit wasn't local firewall on our server, but firewall settings somewhere in the surrounding network. So we asked the server hosting provider to allow NTP for our machines, and now it works fine. For example, `ntpq -p` now returns:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ns1.eunet.fi    192.36.144.23    2 u   10   64    1    1.043    0.258   0.001
 ns2.eunet.fi    62.142.10.44     2 u    9   64    1    0.671    0.135   0.001
 ns3.eunet.fi    62.142.10.44     2 u    8   64    1    0.750    0.277   0.001
```

(We also switched to eunet.fi servers recommenced by the hosting company, but that is beside the point.) The commands in [brent's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/95342/ntp-is-running-system-clock-still-not-in-time-what-gives/95351#95351) were helpful because they made me realise the problem was in network access to the NTP servers, not in NTP configuration itself. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What's the output of 'ntpq -p'?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Stop ntpd, run `ntpdate -u 0.europe.pool.ntp.org` 3 times, start ntpd, check up on `ntpq -p`, delay, offset and jitter should be non-zero.

Comment: And the 'when' field should indicate time since last packet received.

Comment: The ntpdate command returns something like "17 Dec 17:37:29 ntpdate[14195]: no server suitable for synchronization found". However, on other machines the same command gives something meaningful! I'm starting to suspect that some firewall settings for this particular server cause the problem...

Comment: We'll see tomorrow if we can sort out those network/firewall settings. I'll accept this for now, because most likely the problem is related to those. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: The `ntpdate` command works and syncs my clock, but all values are still `0` after I restart `ntp`. Why would it work if I do it manually, but not using `ntpd`? I'm on Debian btw.

Comment: doing that from ntpdate instead of correcting the issue with ntp is pretty useless long-term. and i would know no reason why to run it three times.

Comment: The point was to bring their clock into alignment immediately. In the initial post before the edits, they were not aware that there was a network issue. These commands helped them come to the conclusion that there was a network problem. Running the command 3 times was to ensure the clock was brought into alignment immediately as ntp implementations vary in how they do things. It was to simply be sure the clock was where it should be. Considering this is one of my most upvoted comments, it seems to have helped a lot of people. Thanks for your useful addition nearly 10 years later @FlorianHeigl

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess as to why and assuming you have network connectivity and can see your NTP Host without a problem then it could be you have drifted to a large value. If the time difference is greater than X (Sorry I dont remember what X is offhand) than a warning will be printed and time will not be syncd. You can check your syslog messages for cases of this.

If this is the case stop NTP, run ntpdate host and restart the NTPD this will force a time sync then start keeping it in sync going forward, if you continue to drift that much you may have a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks. In this case the problem seems to be that we cannot see the NTP server without problem - see the comments to brent's answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/95342/ntp-is-running-system-clock-still-not-in-time-what-gives/95351#95351

Answer (score 1):

The "reach" columns being 0 suggests it wasn't able to talk to the servers- iirc it gradually gets bits shifted in to show how the last 8 attempts went (so 377 is good, 0 is bad).

Comment: Yeah, that most likely is the problem; see comments to this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/95342/ntp-is-running-system-clock-still-not-in-time-what-gives/95351#95351

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic ... but remember, NTP has no security. Imagine what a man-in-the-middle attack would do to tons of the world's computers.